# Metodo Java mostrar datas em um loop

Tags: java

Boa noite, tenho um método onde recebo a quantidade de parcelas e data inicial. Quero somar 1 mês a essa data inicial em loop e estou confusa, dando um valor bem diferente:

```
public void faturar(int parcela, String dataFaturamento) {

    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dtFatura = df.parse(dataFaturamento);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dtFatura);
        for (int i = 0; i < parcela; i++) {
            // Através do Calendar, trabalhamos a data informada e adicionamos 1 mês 
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH +1,i);
            Date dtParcelasGeradas = c.getTime();  
            System.out.println(dtParcelasGeradas );
        }
```

Queria que meu System.out.println mostrasse assim:

> 19/09/2016
>   19/10/2016
>   19/11/2016
>   19/12/2016
>   19/01/2017

Mas do jeito que estou fazendo está mostrando assim:

```
Wed Sep 07 00:00:00 BRT 2016   Wed Sep 14 00:00:00 BRT 2016  Wed Sep 28 00:00:00 BRT 2016
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para mostrar no formato DD/MM/YYYY é necessário utilizar **DateFormat.** O grande problema no seu código está apenas na linha c.add(Calendar.MONTH +1,i), o certo é  c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1), pois a função espera qual atributo será incrementado e o segundo parâmetro é a quantidade que será aumentada.

Eu fiz aqui, e funcionou do jeito que você precisava.

```
public static void faturar(int parcela, String dataFaturamento) {


        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dtFatura = null;
        try {
            dtFatura = df.parse(dataFaturamento);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dtFatura);
        for (int i = 0; i < parcela; i++) {
            // Através do Calendar, trabalhamos a data informada e adicionamos 1 mês 
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            Date dtParcelasGeradas = c.getTime();  
            System.out.println(df.format(dtParcelasGeradas ));

        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: obrigada, deu certinho!!! Eu fiz um teste com a data sendo 30/01/2017... a próxima ficou 28/02/2017... e todas as outras ficaram 28/03/2017... em diante. Teria como eu tratar isso?